# Is there a name for linear/homogeneous Galilean transformations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, terminology, galilean-relativity

In Special relativity, the transition charts are Poincaré transformations and linear/homogeneous Poincaré transformations are called Lorentz transformations. (I distinguish between affine transformations and linear transformations.) In Classical Mechanics, the transition charts are Galilean transformations. Is there a name for linear/homogeneous Galilean transformations? I am writing an essay involving Galilean transformation, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

In short, they are just called homogeneous Galilean transformations.

From my little research and understanding of Galilean transformations, there does not seem to be a name for homogeneous Galilean transformations. Some references that discuss the Galilean group of transformations, typically mathematical references, simply refer to them as Galilean transformations or the Galilean group without noting any subgroups in particular. On the other hand, other texts, typically physics references, refer to the subgroup of uniform motion and rotation transformations as homogeneous Galilean transformations or the homogeneous Galilean group. No other name is typically used here.

Mathematical texts that do not mention the term "homogeneous Galilean (transformation/group)":

- Arnol'd, Vladimir Igorevich. Mathematical methods of classical mechanics. Vol. 60. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.
- BÜYÜKYILMAZ, Elif Aybike, Yusuf YAYLI, and G. Ö. K. İsmail. "A new construction of the Sierpinski triangles with Galilean transformations." Mathematical Sciences and Applications E-Notes 4.1 (2016): 151-163. **(This text refers to the uniform motion transformation as the [Shear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) page 157)**
- Duran, Angel, Denys Dutykh, and Dimitrios Mitsotakis. "On the Galilean invariance of some nonlinear dispersive wave equations." Studies in Applied Mathematics 131.4 (2013): 359-388.

Physics texts that refer to them as "homogeneous Galilean (transformation/group)":

- Colussi, V., and S. Wickramasekara. "Galilean and U (1)-gauge symmetry of the Schrödinger field." Annals of Physics 323.12 (2008): 3020-3036.
- von Schultz, Christian. "Galilean Systems in AdS/CFT." (2011).
- Ferrari, L. "The covariance problem and the Hamiltonian formalism in quantum mechanics." Foundations of physics 19.5 (1989): 579-605.
- Bernal, Antonio N., and Miguel Sánchez. "Leibnizian, Galilean and Newtonian structures of space–time." Journal of Mathematical Physics 44.3 (2003): 1129-1149.

This list and these sources are by no means comprehensive or definitive, but just a few references I found while researching Galilean transformations. The divide between math and physics references is also not a clean split, just a pattern that may or may not hold when looking at larger lists of references.

Suggestion: when writing about something not clearly distinguished in literature, I would simply define the term in the text so it is clear to the reader what I mean by that term.